# Particle Effect only playing in game

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add a particle effect-prefab from the StandardAssets to my scene, it only shows some shuriken.
Even the little "Particle Effect" window where you can simulate and pause isn't there.

When I hit "Play" it plays the effect perfectly fine in the game-window.

How do I get this "Particle Effect" window?

Comment: show a screenshot from your editor window

Comment: this question is inconsistent. you don't provide enough information for us to help you. now my guess is that you have some script in the game which sets and fires of the particles in Awake or Start so you don't see it in the editor.